# subplots in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to generate subplots for 6 different values. Currently, I'm only able to do it for `values = 'Sales'` . How can I do it for other 5 variables keeping `columns='Division'`? I'm working with pandas dataframe and need 2 rows and 3 columns for the subplots?

```
subset_sales = (df_2.pivot_table(index=['Response Month (YYYY-MM)'],
                                 columns='Division', values='Sales')
                .reset_index()
                .set_index('Response Month (YYYY-MM)')
                )

subset_sales.plot(rot=90, style={
                  c: i for i, c in zip(subset_sales.columns, subset_sales.columns)})

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample graph:

[image: sample_graph]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. For further question, you should always give an example on how your dataframe looks like.

Comment: There is the official documentation for [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) and tons of [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_subplot.asp) online. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181093/subplot-with-pandas-dataframes

Comment: @tturbo I got it. I have to use 2 for loops and a fig, axes line along with df.plot and that solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Great it helped, can you den maybe accept my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```py
fig, axs = plt.Subplots(n) # for n subplots

# calculate and plot subset 1
subset1 = ...
subset1.plot(ax=ax[0]

# calculate and plot subset 2
subset2 = ...
subset2.plot(ax=ax[1]

...
```